# Why $p \leq n$ implies $p | n!$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Why $p \leq n$ implies $p | n!$ ?

if $n > 2,$ Why $p \leq n$ implies $p | n!$ ?

I was trying to solve: prove that if $n > 2,$ then there exists a prime $p$ satisfying $n < p < n!.$

And the above statement was a part from the following hint given to the solution:

If $n! - 1$ is not a prime, then it has a prime divisor p; and $p \leq n$ implies $p|n!$.

**Edit:**

Why if $p | n!$ then p does not divide $n! - 1$? could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: $n!=1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots n$. If $p\le n$ then it is one of the factors.

Comment: yeah because the factorial include all numbers before it ..... got it thanks! @arctictern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** If $p\leq n,$ the definition of $n!$ is $n!=n\times (n-1)\times \dots \times p\times (p-1)\times \dots \times 1$ so $p|n!.$ For the big question, what is the gcd of $n!$ and $n!-1$? $(n!,n!-1)=?$ so if $p|n!-1$ can it divide $n!$?

Comment: I have edited my question ...... could you please look at it ?

Comment: @hopefully This answer addresses your edit too.

Comment: the gcd is 1 ...... but how to prove this?

Comment: Because for every pair of succesive integers $a,a+1$ you have that if $p|a$ and $p|a+1$ then $p|(a+1-a)$ hence $p|1$ so they have to be coprime.

Comment: why if $n! - 1$ is a prime we are sure that it is greater than n?

Comment: Because $n!-1>n$ for $n>2$ notice that if $n>2$ then $n-1>1$ and then $n!-1>n(n-1)-1=n^2-n-1=(n^2-2n+1)+n-2=(n-1)^2+n-2>1+n-2=n-1$

Comment: can I prove it by induction?

Comment: your idea in your previous comment is not clear for me ....... I can not see that it answer my question ...... could you clarify please?

Comment: Yes, you can prove it by induction :).

Comment: I am stucked in proving it by induction ..... I do not know what to do to prove this $(n+1) < (n+1)! -1$ for $n +1 > 2$

Comment: I understood your proof just now ...... but you proved that $n! - 1 > n-1$ not  $n! - 1 > n$

Comment: The induction: Supposed for $n, $ for $n+1$ is like $(n+1)!-1=(n+1)n!-1=nn!+(n!-1)>nn!+n>n+1$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3229108/how-to-prove-that-n-n-1-for-n-2

Comment: yeah I got it thanks alot