# How to prove that $ n < n! - 1 $ for $n > 2.$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, factorial

How to prove that $ n < n! - 1 $ for $n > 2.$?

I have tried it by induction but I got stucked in the induction step in proving $ n  +1< (n + 1)! - 1 $ for $n + 1> 2$.

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: $n!\ge (n-1)n$.

Comment: then what shall I do next? @LordSharktheUnknown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $n<n!-1$;  i.e., $n+1<n!$.

If we can show $n!<(n+1)!-1$, then we're done showing $n+1<(n+1)!-1$.

$n!<(n+1)!-1 $ is equivalent to $1<(n+1)!-n! = (n+1)n!-n!=(n+1-1)n!=n\times n!$.

Well, if $n>2$ then clearly $1<n\times n!$, so we're done.

Answer (score 4):

*Hint*: $n! \ge 2n$ for $n>2$.

Comment: then what shall I do next?

Comment: @hopefully, 2n> n+1 and you are done. This solution is a direct proof, doesn't use induction.

Comment: @JulianMejia   what do you mean ?

Comment: For $n>2$, we have $n!\geq 2n>n+1$ so, $n<n!-1$. What is the part that is not clear?